# How to index a yaml file using yq with "---" separater

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, yaml, yq

Here is a sample yaml file to explain the issue:

```
hello: null
---
hello: null
```

There are two keys with the same name in a yaml file separated by "---". Both need different values.

I am using yq in a bash script to set the values of certain keys. I am currently using this command for a yaml file without the "---" separater and it works:

```
yq -i -y ".hello=\"world\"" ./$PATH
```

But when I try and index one of the keys in a file with "---" using:

```
yq -i -y ".[0].hello=\"world\"" ./$PATH
```

I get this error:

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:1): Cannot index object with number
jq: error (at <stdin>:2): Cannot index object with number
```

I'm sure the syntax is incorrect but I can't seem to get it to work or find any documentation on this specific problem I'm facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please specify [which implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/yq/info) of yq you are using.

For [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq), you can use `document_index` (or `di`) to [reference into a specific document](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/document-index):

```bash
yq 'select(document_index == 0).hello = "world"'
# or
yq 'select(di == 0).hello = "world"'
```

For [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq), you can use the `--slurp` (or `-s`) [flag](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#Invokingjq) to collect the documents into an array which you can then index into, then iterate over the items to re-generate the multi-document output:

```bash
yq --slurp -y '.[0].hello = "world" | .[]'
# or
yq -sy '.[0].hello = "world" | .[]'
```

Both examples output:

```yaml
hello: world
---
hello: null
```